# Configurable product option values in database

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, attribute-options

Where are configurable product option values, stored in the database?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Magento1.9`

This option label stored in `eav_attribute_option_value` table

For different store its store in separate row

Hope this will help